# Accessing SCNSphere Properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit, scnnode, scnsphere

I am trying to access / modify the properties of an `SCNSphere` that I have in a `SCNScene`. I have the scene pre-set as a file called "spaceScene.scn". I am loading the scene as such

```
self.sceneView.scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"spaceScene.scn"];
self.sceneView.allowsCameraControl = YES;
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
SCNSphere *earth = (SCNSphere *)[self.sceneView.scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"earth" recursively:NO];

NSMutableArray *materials = earth.materials;
NSLog(@"Materials of earth from scene: %@", materials);
```

I can not seem to get past reading the **materials** property of the `SCNSphere` **earth**. I keep getting an instance error:

`-[SCNNode materials]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1701c5550`

Feeling a little silly with this issue but please someone just tell me how to access the sphere properties? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SCNSphere` does **not** inherit from `SCNNode`. You should rather retrieve the node's `geometry` which can be a sphere.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting `SCNNode` to `SCNSphere` when you are creating your `earth` object.

If you take a look at the documentation, the function you are using is returning `SCNNode`.

```
- (SCNNode *)childNodeWithName:(NSString *)name 
                   recursively:(BOOL)recursively;
```

With the casting, you can fake that the object is `SCNSphere`, however, it is not. And when you are sending the `materials` message to the object, it crashes, because it is an unrecognized selector on `SCNNode`.

I would recommend not to force cast, and look for an other way to retrieve you object.

Comment: I understand that unfortunately right after having posted this. Clearly it knows it is NOT a sphere given it's telling me SCNNode materials is the issue. Not sure how else to retrieve the object. Ultimately I am trying to set an SKScene as the surface so I can add and interact with objects on the face of the sphere